# Performance of one-way vs two-way binding in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am making an address book. Other than basic contact details, each contact also has a field of `roles` that itself is an array of different roles. They also have a field of `permissions`, and a field of `certifications`.

My address-book design is like the normal 2-panel design; on the left is the list of all the names. When you select a contact, the details show on the right:

```
<div addressbook>
    <!-- This is the list of names -->
    <div list>

    <!-- This is the selected contact -->
    <div contact>
```

Ideally I wanted to pass the list to `list` using one-way binding. Then the selected contact is two-way binding between `addressbook` and `list` and one-way binding to `contact`:

```
<div addressbook>
    <!-- This is the list of names -->
    <div list="{{ list }}" selected-contact="contact">

    <!-- This is the selected contact -->
    <div contact="{{ contact }}">
```

I'm afraid the app would run slow if I pass the `list` as one-way binding since `{{list}}` becomes a very long string that needs to be parsed to JSON later. I feel that the two-way binding would be faster!

Is this true? Would I run into any performance issues if I keep the code as it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a directive context, it's more helpful to think about the `@`s and `=`s as ["bind to value of a DOM attribute" and "bind to the value of a scope property"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) rather than thinking of it as one-way or two-way.

`@`s are suitable for passing trivial values like short strings or numbers to your directive. When you have something non-trivial like an actual JavaScript object (your `list`) that you need to reference from within your directive, bind it with `=`.

Comment: Okay thanks that makes sense. Now what if I want to make sure that the data is one way binded as well? So in this case,  I don't want the main `list` to change, but maybe the `list` in the child directive could change. How would you do this if you pass the items using `=`?

Comment: in your directive's link function, make a copy of the list, i.e. `scope.myList = angular.copy(scope.list)`. Your code should then reference `scope.myList` rather than `scope.list`.

Comment: Well yeah, but that's not really the best strategy is it? It seems more of a hack than a solution

Comment: A hack is passing in a JS object as a string in a DOM attribute then parsing and transforming it back into a JS object in the directive.

Comment: Fair enough. I still wonder why hasn't angular provided a way to do this without having to duplicate the variable manually. There should then be a 4th scope type for this purpose!!!